# Detect when camera lens is mostly/completely covered

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

In the app Peek, they have a cool little feature where if the user "cups" their hand on the top of their device, they show some information about the item they are looking at.

I am guessing they are using the front facing camera to do this, maybe seeing if it is covered to a certain extent. I have browsed the docs on `MobileCoreServices` and `UIImagePicker` but am not entirely sure where to start.

Does anybody have an idea/starting point on how to achieve similar functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to analyze the camera frame in real time and work on the pixels color...

Comment: Hmm, I am guessing GDC would be needed for something like that then. I can't see this being a cheap process if it's in real time (which I don't know how it wouldn't be in real time)